# Belongs_to primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a DB layout like so:

```
Users
--------------
id, name, etc...

Lead
--------------
id, initials, etc..
```

Basically a user has many leads. The `initials` field maps to the `name` field in the users table. I have a relationship for the users setup that works perfect:

```
has_many :leads, :foreign_key => 'initials', 
                 :primary_key => 'name'
```

But I can't figure out how to do it the other way using `belongs_to`:

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'name', 
                  :primary_key => 'initials'
```

That doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Options should be the same as in `has_many :leads` association:

```
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :initials, primary_key: :name
```

Comment: In which Rails version was it intorduced?

Comment: @czerasz I don't know exactly, but's very old feature. I'm quite sure it has been in Rails 2.x already.