# Define relationship between 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `CourseSession` model. Each `CourseSession` has some `lessons`.

I would like to call: `lesson.course_session` and get the `CourseSession` that refers to the `lesson`.

I don't want to use a foreign key in order to practice rails.

How can I connect between them? Every `Lesson` has a unique `effective_date` column that coresponds to an `effective_date` in the `CourseSession` model.

So how do I define the associations in order to achieve `lesson.course_session`?

Comment: foreign keys have _nothing_ to do with active record relationships. Even if you have them in the db, you still will have to define appropriate `belongs_to` / `has_many`.

Comment: I know that, just don't want the simple answer "add a foreign key"!

Comment: Do your lessons have `course_session_id`? If not, they should. Linking only by date sounds.... unreliable.

Comment: I know, but this is what I want. For practice only.

Comment: Well, start with the topical [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, I guess, but not an advised approach. If it's for the sake of learning something new, go ahead. But anyway, in the Lesson model, use:

```
belongs_to :course_session, primary_key: :effective_date, foreign_key: :effective_date
```

And in CourseSession:

```
has_many :lessons, primary_key: :effective_date, foreign_key: :effective_date
```

Found a post here talking about this: [Belongs_to primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313808/belongs-to-primary-key)

Take a look at https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to under Options/:primary_key

Comment: Not working. Is it possible because I have column effective_date both in CourseSession and in Lesson?

Comment: @NoamB.: not working because you didn't specify `foreign_key` option.

Comment: I copied what @Tiago wrote